# Morris Line Graph set data method not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, graph, morris.js

I have a morris line graph setup like this:

```
 var chart = new Morris.Line({
            // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
            element: 'myfirstchart',
            // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
            // the chart.
            data: [
              { year: '1990', value: 20 },
               { year: '1991', value: 15 },
               { year: '1992', value: 20 },
               { year: '1993', value: 25 },
               { year: '1994', value: 11 },
               { year: '1995', value: 20 },
               { year: '1996', value: 15 },
               { year: '1997', value: 20 },
               { year: '1998', value: 16 },
               { year: '1999', value: 11 },
               { year: '2000', value: 13 },
                { year: '2001', value: 8 },
                 { year: '2002', value: 11 },
                  { year: '2003', value: 16 },
              { year: '2004', value: 10 },
              { year: '2005', value: 5 },
              { year: '2006', value: 5 },
               { year: '2007', value: 4 },
                { year: '2008', value: 8 },
                 { year: '2009', value: 11 },
                  { year: '2010', value: 16 },
              { year: '2011', value: 10 },
              { year: '2012', value: 5 },
              { year: '2013', value: 5 },

              { year: '2014', value: 20 }
            ],
            // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
            xkey: 'year',
            // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
            ykeys: ['value'],
            // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
            // chart.
            labels: ['Value']
        });
```

The data above show is just some test data I randomly setup in graph so that I can see how it looks like....

I do a post method to my server method like this:

```
 $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
     chart.setData(response);
     //  console.log(response);
 });
```

And the action and what it returns:

```
var groupedByDate = new List<GroupedByDate>();
```

And this class contains these two properties:

```
DateTime TransactionDate;
int Sales;
```

And the way I return the result is like this:

```
 return Json(groupedByDate);
```

And the date is in format like this:

```
6/20/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

The error that I'm getting when I try to set up the new data source is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at Object.b.parseDate (morris.min.js:6)
    at c.<anonymous> (morris.min.js:6)
    at c.b.Grid.d.setData (morris.min.js:6)
    at Object.success (:598)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

What am I doing wrong here guys? Can someone help me out ?

@Dynamikus the response is:

```
(7) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Each object looks like this:


0:
Object
Date
:
"2017-06-20"
Sales
:
6
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: make sure the response is a json format. You might use JSON.parse if that is the case also make it sure you have the correct data format for the year property.
What does the console.log show?

Comment: @Dynamikus in that case I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: that happens when you just do console.log? Ignore JSON.parse for the moment.

Comment: @Dynamikus no , the console.log displays the returned result...

Comment: @Dynamikus it looks like this in console log: (7) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: can you paste a sample of the result in here? Most likely you have a date format problem

Comment: @Dynamikus yes one sec i'll paste it in original question :)

Comment: @Dynamikus I posted the reponse in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147754/discussion-between-dynamikus-and-user987).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Morris js config should match your json response. In your scenario

```
  xkey: 'Date',
   // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['Sales'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
   labels: ['Date']
```